# importing a large sql file into mysql

Tags: mysql

can u tell me how to import a 30mb of sql file in mysql.I am using ubuntu.

Comment: search for mysql yog for ubuntu

Answer (score 13):

You have to run the following command

```
mysql -u <user> -p<password> dbname < filename.sql
```

Another alternate is also a command

log in to mysql using `mysql -u <user> -p`

```
mysql > use db_name;
mysql > source filename.sql;
```

Comment: +1. It took me 10 seconds to import a 22MB file using CLI, whereas it was taking around 2 minutes to do the same thing via phpMyadmin

Comment: is this method recommended for 600 MB+ mysql files?

Answer (score 0):

Use [BigDump.php](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump.php)